# Visualizing the set of points whose coordinates sum to zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, visualization

Consider the set 
$$S = \left\{(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \;:\; \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i = 0\right\}$$

I can see that in $1$D, we just have $x_1 = 0$.

In $2$D, we have the line $x_2  = -x_1 \Leftrightarrow y = -x$.

How to visualize in $3$D? Is there a name for this space?

Comment: In 3D it is the plane thru the origin with normal vector $(1,1,1)$ (assuming the equation is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0$).

Comment: Your definition of S strikes me as pretty wrong, to put it bluntly

Comment: Blue 's edit makes me feel better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane).